# wxPython + pysftp won't work at the same time

Tags: python, ssh, connection, wxpython, pysftp

My code:

```
class ConnectingPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, pos=(-2, -2), size=(387, 267))
        self.control.SetForegroundColour((34,139,34))
        self.control.SetBackgroundColour((0,0,0))
        self.control.Disable()

        self.control.AppendText("Connecting to device")
        self.device = Connection(#info goes here)   
        self.control.AppendText("Connected to device")
```

So, as can be seen by my code, I'm trying to generate a panel with a "status" textbox, self.control. The idea is that I'm connecting to a remote device using pysftp, and that I want it to add a line to the status textbox each time an action takes place. The first one is just connecting to the host. However, my panel only displays *once the code has connected to the host*, even though the code for making the panel, etc is before.

What can I do? No errors, just this weird behaviour.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, it is because you are doing this in the constructor.

Use [wx.CallAfter](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#CallAfter):

```
class ConnectingPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, pos=(-2, -2), size=(387, 267))
        self.control.SetForegroundColour((34,139,34))
        self.control.SetBackgroundColour((0,0,0))
        self.control.Disable()

        wx.CallAfter(self.start_connection)

    def start_connection(self):
        self.control.AppendText("Connecting to device")
        self.device = Connection(#info goes here) 
        self.control.AppendText("Connected to device")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modify your panel in the constructor of the panel, but the panel is only displayed after the constructor execution (somewhere after the `.MainLoop()` and/or `.Show()` call).

The correct way of doing this is by registering handlers for events ([cf doc](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CustomEventClasses)) with something like this

```
import  wx.lib.newevent
import threading

class ConnectingPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, pos=(-2, -2), size=(387, 267))
        self.control.SetForegroundColour((34,139,34))
            self.control.SetBackgroundColour((0,0,0))
        self.control.Disable()

        self.MyNewEvent, self.EVT_MY_NEW_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
        self.Bind(self.EVT_MY_NEW_EVENT, self.connected_handler) # you'll have to find a correct event
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_connection)
        thread.start()

    def start_connection(self):
        self.control.AppendText("Connecting to device")
        self.device = Connection(#info goes here)
        evt = self.MyNewEvent()
        #post the event
        wx.PostEvent(self, evt)

    def connected_handler(self, event):
        self.control.AppendText("Connected to device")
```

EDIT: Added a threaded launch for the connection starting to avoid a blocking operation thazt block display.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change a thing. The events seem to work, as both messages are still displayed. However, the window still only appears after the connection has finished.

Comment: @Judge John Deed : I edited my answer to launch the connection in a threaded way to unblock the GUI.

Comment: Merci for your time, but @lack's method is just so much simpler. Thanks again though.